# Is the exponent bias $2^{n-1}-1$ or $2^{n-1}$

Tags: floating-point, numerical-analysis

I'm a bit confused with the exponent bias. The sources I found online claim that it is either $2^{n-1}-1$ or $2^{n-1}$, $n$ is the number of bits used for the exponent. In my book when given examples on the bias of a 32bit system the bias is said to be $2^7$ which means the bias is $2^{n-1}$ while in an example on the bias of 64bit the bias is said to be $2^{11}-1$ which is $2^{n-1}-1$

So which one is it?

Comment: Please see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponent_bias

Comment: yeah I read the wiki, it says the bias is $2^{k-1}-1$. But in my book for 32bit it says it's $2^{k-1}$. You think there's a mistake in my book?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both encodings for the exponent are possible, and they are called Excess-$2^{n-1}$ and Excess-$2^{n-1}-1$ - in particular, you might meet such number encodings as Excess-127, Excess-128, Excess-1023 and so on.

The [IEEE-754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) standard happened to choose the Excess-127 and the Excess-1023 encodings for exponents, so these encodings became more customary. Your book is not mistaken about the exponent bias, it just follows a way, different from this standard.

You can find additional information and nice graphs [here](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/255/Syllabus/5-repr/excess-n.html).

Comment: It's also worth noting that it makes particular sense for IEEE-754 to use excess-$2^{n-1}-1$ because it reserves "all zeroes" for subnormal (previously called "denormal") numbers and "all ones" for Inf/NaN. Using this bias keeps the range of exponents more symmetric around $2^0$.

Comment: Great! I'm super new to computer science so I was confused. Thanks a lot